# Severe thermal throttling unsure what the cause is

Tags: laptop, fan, temperature, cpu-throttling

So awhile back I swapped out my hard drive and ram in my laptop and immediatly after I noticed my pc was running insanely slow after a lot of troubleshooting I found that prochot was throttling my cpu to 400 MHz per second. Disabling it stops the cpu from throttling. I tried putting the original components back which didn't work, reinstalling the windows, trying a different OS. My laptop feels cool to touch even when the fans are loud and I get this weird thing where the fan will be loud for a 10-30 seconds then quiet for 10-30 seconds in an endless loop.  It throttles the second I log in too even after being left off all night in a fairly cold room. I Also tried cleaning it multiple times and made sure to clean it while replacing the parts. Do you have any idea whats causing this?

Comment: You broke, or left off the sensor on the new drive? iMacs were notorious for this, I assume they are not the only machine ever made with a thermal sensor on the HD.

Comment: "as throttling my cpu to 400 mbs per second. " - CPUs are not measured in megabits/sec.  What unit are you attempting to use?

Comment: @Ramhound megahertz sorry I always do that.

Comment: @Tetsujin as I said returning the original drive did not work also I'm pretty sure it was intended to be replaceable since there was only 1 screw and some pins holding it in it also had the pin layout for other types of drives. I think the original was sata and the replacement was nvme. I just checked the original drive there doesn't seem to be anything damaged either.